# How to print first and last line of file in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

What is the best way to print first line and last line of the input file using hadoop map reduce ?

for example if i have a file of 10 GB and typical block size is 128 mb so approximately 
80 mappers would be invoked by keeping the default configuration means not manipulating the split size properly

so now 80 mappers would  be invoked how would i differentiate how framework has assigned the split size means starting split size offset or number to which mapper.

so simply i can't put logic in my map function blindly this way it will be applied to other mappers as well .

one solution i can think of using one mapper by keeping the block size as of file size that way i can put functionality in map function but this way i won't able to make use of parallel computing .

Any Effective way of doing this ?

Comment: Mapper is going to get key and value pair, so how are you going to identify which is first and last? Best place i think for you to look at is inputSplit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try "hadoop fs" commands for this separately store the first and the last line and then run your map reduce jobs on it. hadoop has a specific tail command which directly gives the last n lines in the file.

This is what I tried:

File size: 2.2MB

First Line: Getting first is straight forward, do a cat and take head -n1
    hadoop fs -cat $file | head -n1 
time taken: 4s

Last Line: There are two ways to get this, one is the to do a cat and do a tail. But since the file size if large this would long.

```
hadoop fs -cat $file | tail -n1
```

Time taken: 39 seconds

But luckily there is tail command which comes to rescue here. You can do a hadoo fs -tail on your file and the time taken is same as the head command. As per the documentation : **Displays last kilobyte of the file to stdout. -f option can be used as in Unix**

```
hadoop fs -tail | $file | tail -n1
```

time taken: 4 seconds

You can try this on your file and check the time difference.

Comment: I don't want this way i know through unix utilities you can easily filter no problem at all i wanted to know with respect to map reduce only